# React Native: Component not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am importing a custom component (RecipeCard) and it isn't appearing on the screen.

I'm fairly certain it is to do with the styling that I am currently using.

The fastimage component works exactly as the RN  component does and can be seen [here](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image).

Any help is appreciated!

**File1**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Head
      headerText={this.props.type}
      navigation={this.props.navigation}
      backButton
    />
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RecipeCard {...item} />}
    />
</View>
 const styles = {
   container: {
     flex: 1
   }};
```

**RecipeCard**

```
<FastImage
   style={styles.imageStyle}
   source={{ uri: this.props.image }}
>
  <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>             
       {this.props.title}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>
       {this.props.subtitle}
      </Text>
  </View>
</FastImage>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: 15,
    zIndex: 2,
    bottom: 13,
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: 70,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  titleText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '800',
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingTop: 10
  },
  subtitleText: {
    color: '#adadad',
    fontWeight: '500',
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingTop: 5,
  }
});
```

Comment: You have `backgroundColor: 'transparent',` is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, because i'm using a linear gradient over the top. The image renders if I remove `<FlatList>` and just import `<RecipieCard />`

Comment: And what happens when you `console.log(this.props)` in recipe card?

Comment: The object is passed correctly, if I remove FlatList the image renders to screen (from props) correctly.

Comment: Yes but when it's passed from `FlatList` what does the log show?

Comment: It shows the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the resizeMode to the FastImage:

```
resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
```

It's also described in the docs of FastImage:

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

const YourImage = () =>
  <FastImage
    style={styles.image}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
      headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
      priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
    }}
    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example you have given above, I was able to see the image with a little change in `imageStyle`, just added `height` and it was showing the images.

RecipeCard component

```
const RecipeCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <FastImage
      style={styles.imageStyle}
      source={{ uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1' }}
    >
     <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
       <Text style={styles.titleText}>             
        {props.title}
       </Text>
       <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>
        {props.subtitle}
       </Text>
     </View>
   </FastImage>
 );
}
```

In `imageStyle` I have added `height`

```
imageStyle: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  height: 200
},
```

Hope this helps!